# How do I pass an Argument to a Clang Plugin?

Tags: c++, plugins, arguments, clang

Seeing the existence of [clang::FrontendOptions::PluginArgs](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FrontendOptions.html#a9594af38a8cc905c802e88966f399a0d) I would think it is possible. But I've failed to find any documentation on exactly how to pass arguments to a plugin via command line.

I've tried preceding an argument with `-Xclang`, I've tried combining my plugin with the arguments (e.g., "test-plugin args"), and I've attempted to scour the internet. Anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give arguments to a plugin, you should use the -plugin-arg-your-plugin command. 
For example, if your plugin's name is test-plugin and you want to give it the argument "help", the command would be :

clang -cc1 -load ~/Path/to/your/clang/library -plugin test-plugin -plugin-arg-test-plugin help

Hope it will help

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-Xclang` if you are using clang++ and passing these parameters to clang:

```
clang++ -Xclang -load -Xclang ~/Path/to/your/library -Xclang -plugin -Xclang your-library-name -Xclang -plugin-arg-your-library-name -Xclang help
```